# Editable GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to allow for editing of the items in a GridView (the DataSource is a database connection). Every example I find has complicated examples implemented within. I'd like to know what the simplest change(s) I need to do are in order to allow for editing of items in the GridView.

In other words, how can I modify the following to allow for editing?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceWS">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" HeaderText="NAME" SortExpression="NAME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ACCESS_TO" HeaderText="ACCESS_TO" SortExpression="ACCESS_TO" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Obviously I'd need to add code as well, but I'm just not sure how to start with this.

EDIT: I thought I'd specified, but I didn't - it's an SQLDataSource.

Comment: What is the data source SQL or Object? see this link it may be helpful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx

Comment: It's an SQLDataSource. I'll check this out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several thing you need to do to enable editing

Assuming that your data source is an SQLDataSource

**1)** Add a command field to your girdview columns

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" EditText="Edit" ShowEditButton="true"/>
```

**2)** Add an update command to your data source

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceWS" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ Connection String %>" 

    SelectCommand="  SELECT COMMAND HERE " 
    UpdateCommand="  UPDATE COMMAND HERE ">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

For more information on the command field and how to use it you can look at the  [Microsoft Developer Network Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield.aspx)

**EDIT**

Here is a very simple example of a SQLDatasource that shows how you may update an item

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlMeetings" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ connection %>" 

            SelectCommand="SELECT  [meetingid]
                              ,[groupname]
                              ,[meetingtime]
                              ,[meetingdate]
                          FROM [DCMS].[dbo].[tbl_meetings] " 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE tbl_meetings 
                           SET meetingdate = @meetingdate, meetingtime = @meetingtime 
                            WHERE meetingid = @meetingid">
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="meetingdate" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="meetingtime" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

From the example above you can see that I am selecting 3 fields from the data base but only allowing for two to be updated (meetingdate and meetingtime).

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate a bit on the UpdateParameters? How will it know which field I'm working on and how do I use the parameters in the query?

Comment: @rar Your parameter names would be the name of your database fields that you are updating. I have added a simple example to my answer of what a data source might look like when updating.

Answer (score 0):

To edit the records, the GridView must enter EditMode. The grid changes modes according to the commands it receives, in this case "edit". See the remarks on the [gridview page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx), 'Data Operations' section, for more info.

There are basically three ways to fire the command and enter edit mode on the grid:

1. Use the [AutoGenerateEditButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogenerateeditbutton.aspx) property on the grid
2. Use a [CommandField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield.aspx) with ShowEditButton like the other answer stated
3. Use a custom [TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx) with a [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) inside like this:

```
<Columns>
...
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
...
</Columns>
```

After that, it will depend on which DataSource control you are using. With an [EntityDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.aspx), for instance, all you need to do is set [EnableUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.enableupdate.aspx)="true"

Comment: It'd be an SQLDataSource.